# VBA code for creating Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have created a macro that builds a pivot table. It runs great but I want to dismiss the circled content in the screenshot provided .. I dont want to have the total inside the pivot. Only at the bottom the Grand Total! I am providing my code and a screenshot. Moreover, is it possible to substitute the "Row Labels" text in column B with "FDD"?

[image]

[image]

```
     Sub aa()

 'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Customs_report").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Customs_report"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Customs_report")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Zeikan")

    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(6, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="PivotTable")

    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Commodity Code")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .Name = "Commodity Code"
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Location")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
    End With

    'Insert Column Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Quantity (cases/sw)")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    .Name = "Sum of Quantity (cases/sw)"
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Quantity (items)")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    .Function = xlSum
    .Name = "Sum of Quantity (items)"
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Net value")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 3
    .Function = xlSum
    .Name = "Sum of Net value"
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Gross weight (Kg)")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 4
    .Function = xlSum
    .Name = "Sum of Gross weight (Kg)"
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Net weight (Kg)")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 5
    .Function = xlSum
    .Name = "Sum of Net weight (Kg)"
    End With


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can toggle the subtotals:

```
With PTable.PivotFields("Commodity Code")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.Name = "Commodity Code"
.Subtotals(1) = True
.Subtotals(1) = False
End With
```

to change the header, change the table layout to tabular

```
PTable.LayoutRowDefault = xlTabularRow
```

before you add the fields. BTW, you should be using `PTable` rather than `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")` in the rest of your code.

Comment: Perfect! I will accept the answer in 5 minutes because it does not allow me! How about the second part of the question? any solution?

Comment: One last question! I updated a picture of my excel to show you the problem.. The last row has blank as a row value... why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas Your source range is too big. You should be using `Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(6, 1).Resize(LastRow - 5, LastCol)` since it starts in row 6.